# Регулярное выражение, выделяющее весь текст между символами с возможностью экранировать эти символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Можно ли составить регулярное выражение, которое из

```
"text1\"text2" "text3"
```

будет получать:

> text1\"text2

и

> text3

Моих навыков хватило только на что-то подобное:

```
(?<=")([\S\s]+?)(?=")
```

Не смог придумать как заставить это выражение игнорировать кавычку, если перед ней стоит обратный слеш.

Comment: Вроде этого? `re.findall(r'"((?:\\"|.)*?)"', r'"text1\"text2" "text3"')`

Comment: Да, вроде, оно. Спасибо